# Android apply style to custom TextView

Tags: android, themes, textview

I have a class, **TextViewStyled**, which extends TextView

In my theme XML, how do I apply a style to all my **TextViewStyled** widgets on Activities with a chosen theme?

I have this simple theme, but I want to limit the Black Gold style to **TextViewStyled** Widgets without specifying the Black Gold in the TextViewStyled style attribute. This is one of many themes which will be switched dynamically.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyThemeOneofMany" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:???????????">@style/TextViewStyled_Black_Gold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextViewStyled_Black_Gold" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">            
          <item name="android:background">#1E1921</item>        
          <item name="android:textColor">#A85E4F</item>
          <item name="android:textColorLink">#FFBC4F</item>
          <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>               
      </style>


</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that updating the styles works when overriding the base `textview` class after the `inflation` event.

Comment: can you please provide code, how you do it? or what you put in ??? marks <style name="MyThemeOneofMany" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:???????????">@style/TextViewStyled_Black_Gold</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 20):

For **AppCompat** theme (2.3.3+):

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/PizzaSizeWidget</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTextView" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:background">#1E1921</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#A85E4F</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">93sp</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: should be `CustomTextView` instead of `PizzaSizeWidget`?

Answer (score 2):

In order to set the style for TextViews in your custom Theme use the name "android:textViewStyle":

```
<style name="MyThemeOneofMany" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextViewStyled_Black_Gold</item>
</style>
```

Found it when looking through the official android themes.xml [[click]](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml).